# Cucumber::Rake::Tasks not using ruby --1.9?

Tags: cucumber, rake, jruby, factory-bot

We are trying to use Rake to run Cucumber tests on our build server.  Everything has been running fine for a few weeks, but last night we started seeing an error

```
C:\jruby-1.6.7\bin\jruby.exe --1.9 -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\jruby-1.6.7\bin\rake manual_tests
(in <local_folder_name>)
C:/jruby-1.6.7/bin/jruby -I "C:/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib;lib" "C:/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber" --dry-run --format html --out results/manual-tests.html --format progress --tags ~@wip --tags @manual
C:/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-3.1.0/lib/factory_girl/null_factory.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':'

delegate :defined_traits, :callbacks, :attributes, :constructor, to: :definition
                                                                   ^ (SyntaxError)
```

Upon further investigation we found that this is a new hash syntax for Ruby --1.9, and all other sites suggest upgrading or specifying in jruby to use --1.9.  However, we have already set all possible options to use Ruby 1.9, and yet we are still seeing this error.

To make it even weirder, we are also using Rake to run some rspec unit tests, using the same code base, just the tests are different.  It works just fine in rspec, leading us to wonder if the error has to do with Cucumber::Rake::Tasks not recognizing that we are in Ruby 1.9

Here is the command line argument being run, which you can clearly see is running --1.9:

```
 C:\jruby-1.6.7\bin\jruby.exe --1.9 -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\jruby-1.6.7\bin\rake manual_tests
(in <local_folder_name>)
C:/jruby-1.6.7/bin/jruby -I "C:/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib;lib" "C:/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber" --dry-run --format html --out results/manual-tests.html --format progress --tags ~@wip --tags @manual
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, or even why it would just start happening without any apparent relevant changes, we would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

We finally did solve this issue, and as expected it was that while JRuby and Cucumber were setup to use --1.9, when we tried to run it through rake, it was still trying to use --1.8.  To solve the issue we created an environment variable for rake for the build:

```
JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
```

We are still not sure why this was working before, and only just started failing recently, so please feel free to comment if you have any ideas.  Thanks.